# Photoshop CS4 - File saving error "File in use"

Tags: adobe-photoshop, save, cs4, file-format

I'm using Photoshop CS4 on a Mac.  I'm constantly getting this error when I try to save a PSD:

Could not save "file-name.psd" because the file is already in use or was left open.

I have to end up saving the file with a 1 appended and then delete/rename.  Any one have some idea how to get around this?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a Mac specific problem. Its either you have the file selected in your finder. Try deselecting it, then saving again.

I also found this too at Macforums.

Go to Photoshop > Preferences > File Handling
And underneath "image previews - Always save"
Make sure that "Icon" is UNCHECKED. It must be the case that this is conflicting with the Finder's own icon generation, hence the finder not "letting go" of the file.